# Cannot find the error with my query in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database, gridview

I have a gridview and linkbuttons at every row of this gridview. When i click one of the buttons, i get the values of the courseName,courseCode and term column values of this row. Here is my code:

```
 int row = -1;
        int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument as string, out row);

        GridViewRow gdrow = instCourses.Rows[row];

        // *** Get the underlying data item - in this case a DataRow
        DataRow dr = ((DataTable)this.instCourses.DataSource).Rows[gdrow.DataItemIndex];

        // *** Retrieve our context
        string courseCode = dr["CourseCode"].ToString();
        string courseNumber = dr["CourseNumber"].ToString();
        string term = dr["Term"].ToString();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = Userfunctions.GetConnectionString();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select RegisterTable.StudentID,StudentTable.Name,StudentTable.Surname from RegisterTable INNER JOIN StudentTable where RegisterTable.StudentID=StudentTable.StudentID and RegisterTable.CourseCode=@courseCode and RegisterTable.Term=@term and RegisterTable.CourseNumber=@courseNumber",con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@courseCode", courseCode);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@courseNumber", courseNumber);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term", term);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        studList.DataSource = dt;
        studList.DataBind();
```

The values return as i expect, but i think there is something wrong with my query, it says Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'. Can anyone see the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query syntax is not correct. Try:

```
SELECT 
    RegisterTable.StudentID,
    StudentTable.Name,
    StudentTable.Surname 
FROM RegisterTable 
INNER JOIN StudentTable ON RegisterTable.StudentID = StudentTable.StudentID
WHERE 
    RegisterTable.CourseCode = @courseCode 
    AND RegisterTable.Term = @term 
    AND RegisterTable.CourseNumber = @courseNumber
```

You need to change the `WHERE` to `ON` to complete the `JOIN`, and then you should move the rest of the criteria to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks, that worked the only thing is the name of the column in student table is ID, not StudentID when i fixed it that worked, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Format your sql query and you'll see the problem:

```
select RegisterTable.StudentID,StudentTable.Name,StudentTable.Surname 
from RegisterTable INNER JOIN StudentTable 
where RegisterTable.StudentID=StudentTable.StudentID 
and RegisterTable.CourseCode=@courseCode 
and RegisterTable.Term=@term 
and RegisterTable.CourseNumber=@courseNumber
```

There is no `ON` clause in the join.

```
from RegisterTable INNER JOIN StudentTable 
    ON RegisterTable.StudentID=StudentTable.StudentID 
where ....
```

By the way, in C# you can use a verbatim [string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to format your sql:

```
string sql = @"
    SELECT registertable.studentid, 
           studenttable.name, 
           studenttable.surname 
    FROM   registertable 
           INNER JOIN studenttable 
                   ON registertable.studentid = studenttable.studentid 
    WHERE  registertable.coursecode = @courseCode 
           AND registertable.term = @term 
           AND registertable.coursenumber = @courseNumber";
```

Then it's easier to locate errors in your sql-queries.

Answer (score 1):

You have an inner join with out ON

```
select RegisterTable.StudentID,StudentTable.Name,StudentTable.Surname from RegisterTable INNER JOIN StudentTable ON RegisterTable.studentid = StudentTable .id  where RegisterTable.StudentID=StudentTable.StudentID and RegisterTable.CourseCode=@courseCode and RegisterTable.Term=@term and RegisterTable.CourseNumber=@courseNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the join condition here

```
FROM RegisterTable INNER JOIN StudentTable
```

Your inner join should looks like this

```
from RegisterTable INNER JOIN StudentTable 
   ON RegisterTable.StudentID = StudentTable.StudentId
```

According your where clause, your query could be written without using inner join, simply using a cartesian product.

```
select 
        RegisterTable.StudentID,
        StudentTable.Name,
        StudentTable.Surname 
from    RegisterTable, StudentTable 
where   RegisterTable.StudentID=StudentTable.StudentID and 
        RegisterTable.CourseCode=@courseCode and 
        RegisterTable.Term=@term and 
        RegisterTable.CourseNumber=@courseNumber
```

Comment: You only need one `=` in that SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify which column from each table to join `StudentTable` on using `ON` instead of `WHERE`:

```
SELECT RegisterTable.StudentID, StudentTable.Name, StudentTable.Surname
FROM RegisterTable
INNER JOIN StudentTable ON RegisterTable.StudentID = StudentTable.StudentID
WHERE RegisterTable.CourseCode = @courseCode
    AND RegisterTable.Term = @term
    AND RegisterTable.CourseNumber = @courseNumber
```